# How to Make `X` to 0 in minimum number of steps?

Tags: algorithms

You are given a number `X`. You can perform any of the two operations on `X` in each move:

1. If we take two integers `a` and `b`, such that `X` is a product of `a` and `b` (`a != 1`, `b != 1`), then we can modify `X = max(a, b)`.
2. Decrement the value of `X` by `1`.

Find out the minimum number of moves required to reduce `X` to `0`.

What I have tried is greedy approach. I factorized the number closest to its square root, and then proceed backwards. If the number is prime, I just do `-1`. Is this approach correct?

My approach to this question:

```
// Author - Rajat Saxena (bloodphoenix)
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define M           1000000007
#define nl          cout << endl
#define pb          push_back
#define F           first
#define S           second
#define stuff(a,v)  memset(a,v,sizeof a)
#define whatis(x)   cout << #x << " = " << x << endl
#define FAST        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
using namespace std;
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const map<T1,T2> &m)
{
    for (const auto &p : m)
    {
        os << p.first << "->" << p.second << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
template <typename T1>
void printData(const T1 &data)
{
    for (auto i = begin(data) ; i != end(data) ; ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}
// Date - 27 June 2017 (Tuesday) 01:50 AM

int dp[1000006];

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FAST
    stuff(dp,-1);
    dp[0] = 0;
    dp[1] = 1;
    dp[2] = 2;
    dp[3]= 3;
    for (int i = 4; i < 1000001; ++i)
    {   
        int d = sqrt(i);
        int ans = INT_MAX;
        bool flag = false;
        for (int j = d; j >= 2; --j)
        {
            if(i%j == 0)
            {
                ans = min(ans,dp[max(j,i/j)]);
                flag = true;
            } 
        }

        if(flag)
            dp[i] = 1 + ans;
        else
            dp[i] = 1 + dp[i-1];
    }

    int t; cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int x; cin >> x;
        cout << dp[x] << endl;

    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking is "correct"?  Since you have defined the rules, presumably you are asking either about correctly finding the shortest path from $X$ to $0$, or about the code being correct.  I don't know why the code was included, but checking your programming is off-topic here.

Comment: Certainly when $X$ is prime we will use the $-1$ rule, and plausibly one can avoid that rule except when $X$ is prime.  However the choice of "nearest to square root" for composite $$ is not optimal, e.g. $X=60$.  Then $X=12*5$ is better than  $X=10*6$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer, but rather an extended comment.

The method is not right. Take $258$. Your approach gives $258, 43, 42, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0$, totaling $8$ moves.

On the other hand, $258, 257, 256, 16, 4, 2, 1, 0$ is $7$ moves.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not optimal in all cases. For the case of 59, the greedy progression of $59, 58, 29, 28, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0$ is 9 steps. But $59,58,57,56,8,4,2,1,0$ is 8 steps. In general if $x$ is close to a number that has a factor of $2^n$, where is n is say 3 or more, then the greedy approach may be sub-optimal.

Being close to a square may be another place where greedy is sub-optimal. For example 83, 123, 147, 171 where the greedy approach has the same number of steps as step-to-nearest square approach. I suspect with more searching a square would be found that has fewer steps with later approach.